# Shall I use Present simple for fixed timetables

Tags: present-tense

I am 30 next month or I am going to be 30 next month

I think you can use present as it is a fixed timetable

Am I right?

Comment: I'll be 30 [years old] next month. I'm going to be 30 [years old] next month. Those are the most usual ways  of saying this.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t use simple present for a single event in the future; you need to use the simple future (will be) or going-to future (going to be): I will eat lunch at noon tomorrow.

Simple present *can* be used for repeated events that continue into the future: I eat lunch at noon every day.

Comment: "You can’t use simple present for a single event in the future" - I disagree with this a bit.  It's very common to use it for plans, like "I leave for France tomorrow."

Comment: @stangdon— I agree with you. Perhaps this is why _future tense_ is no longer considered a valid tense anymore.

Comment: That is a matter of a pinion of hullers and pullers. Not everyone agrees with that.

Comment: @stangdon Is there a rule that says when that’s acceptable? I don’t do it myself, so I’ve never thought about it.

Comment: @StephenS It seems to be mostly used for things that are planned or scheduled, like "The show starts at 9 PM", or "The lease expires in 2055."  By way of comparison, "It rains tomorrow" sounds really weird and wrong.  I also think it's mostly used for simple statements: "When I retire, I move to California" sounds wrong.  Reference: https://continuingstudies.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/410/grammar/410-expressing-the-future#:~:text=The%20Present%20Simple%20Tense%20for,timetables%2C%20airline%20schedules%2C%20etc.&text=The%20meeting%20is%20in%20the,It%20begins%20at%2010%3A00.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to another answer, to me all three possibilities are perfectly normal. There is absolutely nothing wrong with *I'm thirty next month*.